# systemd seems to ignore my "User=" and "Group=" setting

Tags: systemd, mariadb, fedora-22

I'm running mariadb as a different user than the standard mysql.
To this end, I've updated the service file and replaced

```
User=mysql
Group=mysql
```

with

```
User=someuser
Group=somegroup
```

This used to work fine, but after a recent re-install I'm unable to get MariaDB running. Every time it loads it complains it doesn't have permission to access the files which `someuser` clearly does.

System: Fedora 22, MariaDB 10.0

Anyone have any idea how I can check if systemd is really running the service as the correct user?

thanks,
  Michael

Comment: How are you verifying that `someuser` does have permissions to access those files?  Is SELinux running?  Are there additional ACLs on the files that might be getting in the way?  Though there are probably better ways, one way you could check the user would be to replace ExecStart with a script that logs its euid etc.

Comment: I'm simply becoming that user and checking manually. Will check selinux, thanks

Comment: selinux was getting in the way. Fixed now. Thanks!!!

Comment: @MichaelClerx Can you post that, with as much detail as you can, as an answer?

Comment: @mattdm sure! I was waiting for Eric Renouf to do it so I could accept his answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Following a hint from Eric Renouf I checked my selinux settings.
It turns out I always have it disabled and had forgot to disable it after reinstalling.

Disabling selinux made the issue go away.

Comment: You can all shoot me now for disabling selinux :-D
It's a single-user workstation with all the server ports closed, so I don't need the added complications.